# Center 3 divs horizontal fullscreen

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6, fullscreen, center

Please refer to the image below (browserscreen):
A, B, C and D are divs. A and C have a fixed height and width= 100%.
D is a div centered in B.
Can someone please help with the css-code to accomplish this?

Must be compatible with IE6 if possible.

[image: This is your browserscreen]

Comment: HAve you tried anything?

Comment: Does D have a fixed height or dynamic ?

Comment: @Dominic: It has a fixed height

Comment: @Kyle: I'll post my solution so far

Comment: Some people (including me) would not like the idea but using an HTML table with 3 rows and a centered DIV inside row 2 would work if you need to support IE6. Otherwise you'd have to use a bit of CSS and [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to make IE6 properly layout elements the same way as other browsers would do.

Comment: no table please: see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WMneu/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a various css property to getting this. This is one sample change this with your dependency

```
#A{
height: 100px;
background-color: orange;
}
#B{
height: inherit;
}
#D{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: 70px;
margin-left:-100px;
}
#C{
height: 100px;
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/8Qjsa/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="a">
  </div>
  <div id="b">
     <div id="d">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="c">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
width:500px;
background:red;   
}
div#a{
height:100px;
width:100%;
border:2px solid black;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#b{
height:300px;
width:100%;
border:2px solid black;
}
#c{
margin-top:20px;
height:100px;
width:100%;
border:2px solid black;
}
div #d{
height:200px;
width:70%;
background:blue;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:50px;
}
```

I don't know if this is compatible with IE6. You can try. 
I have put the border just for a test purpose. you can remove it in CSS.
JS Fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/sqrcE/

Comment: Thanks, It's not fullscreen in width and height :-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand exactly what you mean. You can input the body height to control the overall page height. Similar you can change the body's width into pixel for desired results. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this html & css:
HTML:

```
<div class="box-wrap">
<div id="A">A</div>
<div id="B">
    <div id="D">D</div>
</div>
<div id="C">C</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-wrap{
border: 1px solid #000000;
height: 267px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 5px;
width: 357px;
}
#A{margin-bottom:5px;}
#C{margin-top:5px;}
#A,
#C{
background:#857a60;
height:70px;
width:100%;
}
#D{
background:#0096FF;
height: 93px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 219px;
}
#B{
background: #857A60;
display: table-cell;
height: 117px;
position: static;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 357px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_vadnal/JjPcX/3/